# Is there any simple way to change the PID and Logs location in Rails application ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to change the default location of the PID file and make it at /var/run and the logs to /var/logs, is there any simple way to do so with rails ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh found it ..

```
sudo rails s --pid=/var/run/rails.pid --log=/var/log/rails.log
```